# Is an Anaconda Commerical Edition License Required for conda-forge Repositories?

Tags: anaconda

I think I need to get a commercial license for Anaconda following their recent license changes. I was curious though, does accessing the conda-forge repository necessitate the need for a commercial license since it is a community repository? Or does that only apply to the main anaconda repositories? I haven't been able to find information about this.

Comment: I'm not a legal expert on this, but AFAIK, Conda Forge doesn't add anything additional onto the software other than the BSD 3-Clause for the *feedstocks* themselves (i.e., the recipes maintainers write). Otherwise, the software distributed through Conda Forge is whatever the original software was. That is, you still need to verify the individual packages for licenses compatible with your use case.

Comment: yes. I understand the need to be careful about licensing for individual packages, but the Anaconda commercial license is for commercial access to the Anaconda repositories and I am looking for if a commercial license is required for commercial access to the conda-forge repository or if that commercial license only applies to the main anaconda license. https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-commercial-edition-faq

Comment: okay, yeah the TOS cover specifically the use of repo.anaconda.com, which is where Conda Forge and all other user channels are served through. For me, that would require commercial licensing for pretty much any company using Conda in a typical way. I don't know of any independent way of accessing the Conda Forge package builds.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got an email from the support with the following information.

> Conda forge is not covered under the terms of service, so you're free
> to use that repo without restriction.

So the new commercial license only applies to the main Anaconda repositories.

There is this blog post to reference as well https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-11-20-anaconda-tos/