# Can PyInstaller from native Python include low-level dependencies like it does when using from Conda?

Tags: python, build, conda, pyinstaller, glibc

We need to deploy Python 3 script on RHEL 7.9 that has Python 2.7.5 and GLIBC 2.27. Don't have sudo privileges there, so we need to somehow bundle the whole project with all dependencies.

PyInstaller works perfectly, but only when used from Conda environment. On native Python it produces much smaller package and bin execution returns error:

```
[3989] Error loading Python lib '/path/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /path/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
```

Conda build has 202 elements in build dir:

[image]

While build with regular Python only 31:

[image]

**Is there a way to build the project with all low-level dependencies like with Conda but using some free license tool?**

Comment: Could you expand on what you think the "licensing" issue is? Is the Conda one unusable for some reason?

Comment: We need it for commercial use, which in free edition isn't allowed.
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-commercial-edition-faq

Comment: Are you sure that prohibits Conda (e.g., Miniforge + `nodefaults`)? Seems to only pertain to Anaconda distribution and its Anaconda Cloud channel.

Comment: Good question. From what I read though the licence is the same:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/jnywn7/is_miniconda_free_for_commercial_use/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65256884/570918. That reddit thread is about Miniconda, which is still an Anaconda Inc. software. Miniforge is through Conda Forge and only uses Conda Forge channels (though I suggest also including the `nodefaults` channel to explicitly avoid the Anaconda Inc. channels).